# Webcam video takes a longer time to record using Python's VideoCapture

Tags: python, opencv, video, webcam, video-capture

I have this function that records a video using a webcam:

```
def capture_video(webcam_video):
    video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0, cv2.CAP_DSHOW)
    output = cv2.VideoWriter(webcam_video, 
    cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v'), 29.97, (640, 480))

    frames_counter = 300
    while(frames_counter > 0):
        # Capture each frame of webcam video
        # frameRead - bool indicting if the frame was read correctly
        frameRead, frame = video_capture.read()

        output.write(frame)
        frames_counter -= 1

    # close the already opened camera
    video_capture.release()
    # close the already opened file
    output.release()
    # close the window and de-allocate any associated memory usage
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

This produces a video that is 10 seconds long, however it takes 20 seconds to record it.

Why is this the case?

How would I be able to get the recording time to match the length of the video that it produces?

Comment: Note: I tested it on a different windows computer and I didn’t have this problem. What might cause this issue on the other windows?

Comment: Do the webcams of both machines support the selected resolution and framerate? If a machine doesn't, then one possibility is that it serves frames in its default resolution and FPS, which could be HD-quality frames at 30 or 60 FPS for modern devices. That's quite a lot of bandwidth so could explain the slowdown.